# Can't find plugins in menu for wordpress 3.2?

Tags: plugins

Wordpress changed quite a bit from 3.1 to 3.2. I have played for an hour to find the plugin section but not success. Usually they would be on the left hand side in the menu. Now they are not there. Anyone knows where to find them and how to install them on xyz.wordpress site?

This image is from 3.1. Plugin option is second from top.

[image]

Here is 3.2 menu. Can you find Plugins?

[image]

Comment: The Plugins menu?

Comment: It appears an option in the menu. It is not there.

Comment: For me, it's right here: http://i.imgur.com/Hji5P.png. Also, are you able to write posts? For me, I had to enable the `json` module for PHP to be able to write posts and use the interface properly.

Comment: are you using .wordpress site? I have it in 3.1 on my domain but not on new .wordpress.com domain which is 3.1. You sure you are using 3.2?

Comment: Oh, no. I am running 3.2 on my own server from home. The answer below explains it extremely well. Plugins let you execute PHP code, which might be a security hole for the host.

Comment: I dont have access to the edit as well. Dont know where to put this code. It needs to be fixed by wordpress but their online help is closed for 2 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Wordpress Customer Support, they don't allow plugins on .wordpress.com website for security reasons, which kind of sucks. The plugins should work on your own domain/site though.

Answer (score 1):

```
$menu_perms = get_site_option( 'menu_items', array() );
if ( ! is_multisite() || is_super_admin() || ! empty( $menu_perms['plugins'] ) ) {
$count = '';
if ( ! is_multisite() && current_user_can( 'update_plugins' ) )
    $count = "<span class='update-plugins count-$plugin_update_count'><span class='plugin-count'>" . number_format_i18n($plugin_update_count) . "</span></span>";

$menu[65] = array( sprintf( __('Plugins %s'), $count ), 'activate_plugins', 'plugins.php', '', 'menu-top menu-icon-plugins', 'menu-plugins', 'div' );

$submenu['plugins.php'][5]  = array( __('Installed Plugins'), 'activate_plugins', 'plugins.php' );

if ( ! is_multisite() ) {
        /* translators: add new plugin */
        $submenu['plugins.php'][10] = array( _x('Add New', 'plugin'), 'install_plugins', 'plugin-install.php' );
        $submenu['plugins.php'][15] = array( _x('Editor', 'plugin editor'), 'edit_plugins', 'plugin-editor.php' );
    }
}
```

Due to the code above (`wp-admin/menu.php`, line `177`) you can see the 'Plugins' menu:

1. If your Wordpress installation is not multi-site,
2. If it is multi-site and you are the superadmin,
3. If Wordpress option `'menu_items'` array contains the `'plugins'` in it.

Other additional requirement is that you have to have `'activate_plugins'` capability.
Check those conditions to understand why you don't see the `'Plugins'` menu item in your Wordpress dashboard.

Comment: This is a great answer.

Comment: It is a multi-site. Man didn't expect such code :)

Comment: Actually I dont see the edit option in menu too, so I can't edit the code. Unless there is way to use ftp and I can download the file and edit.